# Rails, Capybara: Tests not working anymore after rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I pushed my project to heroku and after that, my capybara-tests stopped working. I guess, the problem lies in rake assets:precompile, because this seems to be the only command, which affects my local code somehow.

Whereas my tests worked as expected, every test now returns the same error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
       Firing a click at co-ordinates [91.5, 69.5] failed. Poltergeist 
detected another element with CSS selector 'html body.container article.ng-scope div.ng-scope nav-bar.ng-scope nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse div.container-fluid div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2.collapse.navbar-collapse' at this position. 
It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

First, I thought, in order to make the tests work again, I run rake assets:clean to delete the assets. But the errors remain.

Then, I deleted the public file with the assets. But the errors remain the same.

Does anyone know, how I can fix this problem?

EDIT 1:

Here is an example of one of my tests:

```
  scenario "User adds a comment" do

    anotheruser = User.create!(email: "anotheruser@gmail.com",
                               password: "abcdefgh123",
                               password_confirmation: "abcdefgh123")
    argumentation = Argumentation.create(title: "Metaphysik und Natur", content: "Man könnte meinen, Metaphysik und Naturwissenschaften haben etwas gemeinsam.", user_id: anotheruser.id)

    argument = Argument.create(title: "Naturwissenschaft als Fortsetzung der Metaphysik", content:"Es gibt Leute, die sagen, Wissenschaft ist die Beantwortung von metaphysischen Fragen.", argumentation_id: argumentation.id, place: 1)
    log_in(email, password)
    visit "/argumentation#!/" + argumentation.id.to_s
    fill_in "argumentcommenttitle", with: "Das ist mein Kommentar dazu!"
    fill_in "argumentcomment", with: "Die Argumentation ist gültig, doch sind die Prämissen falsch"
    click_button "Kommentar erstellen"
    expect(page).to have_content("Das ist mein Kommentar dazu!")
    expect(page).to have_content("Die Argumentation ist gültig, doch sind die Prämissen falsch")

  end
```

EDIT 2:

A commentor asked for a screenshot, here it is:

And the commentor is right, the problem seems not to be about rake assets:precompile, but another. Thanks for the hint! (I'm wondering though, why rake assets:precompile affects the size of the screen in capybara.

[image]

Comment: Curious. I'd have Capybara/Poltergeist write a few screenshots to see what it "sees".

Comment: You should not have to run `rake assets:precompile` if you [have setup the assets pipeline on heroku correctly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-4-asset-pipeline). Heroku will do it in a post commit hook - a much better solution that eliminates bad deploys where you forgot to compile the assets and leads to less churn in the git history.

Comment: @Wukerplank Can you please write an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks for your suggestion. Or should I delete my question?

Comment: @Metaphysiker Glad I could help! I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the error log made me curious:

```
It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

I suggest to have Capybara/Poltergeist make few screenshots to see what it "sees".